# Como fazer que ao clicar numa tecla um submit é enviado

Tags: javascript, html

Bom é o seguinte, eu tenho um chat no meu site, o chat tem um campo de texto e um botão send que é para enviar. Ou seja a pessoa digita no texto e depois tem que clicar no send.

Eu gostaria de saber como faria para que ao clicar-se enter, o submit fosse enviado. Ou seja que não fosse preciso ir clicar no botao submit de enviar, mas que bastasse apenas apertar enter para enviar a mensagem.

Código do submit:

```html
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> WAIT..." id="send_massage" style="margin-right:6px;">SEND</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode fazer assim: ([fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155263/3517631))

```
$("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#id_of_button").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado, resultou perfeitamente.

Comment: -1, se possível adicione à [fonte dessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/155263/4843158). Após adicionar a fonte eu retiro o -1.

Comment: @Gonçalo Então, marca a resposta dele como certa, bruh!!!

Comment: @Randrade eu não tinha visto isso. Bem, o mesmo pra mim.

Comment: Fonte adicionado, tinha esquecido de colocar. Bom que resolveu seu problema.

Comment: Agora sim! @Gonçalo Marca como resposta, cara!

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade você pode enviar o form por qualquer tecla.

Veja esse exemplo no [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/600bov3r/) que eu montei. Você pode colocar qualquer código de tecla.

Os códigos podem ser vistos [aqui](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes), basta digitar a tecla específica no formulário e o código aparece ao lado.

**CÓDIGO**

```js
$('input[name="texto_exemplo"]').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which === 32) { /* 32 é a tecla de espaço, use 13 para [ENTER]*/
    if($('form[name="exemplo"]').submit()){
      alert("Formulário enviado!");
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" name="exemplo" method="POST">
  <input type="text" accesskey="s" name="texto_exemplo"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Eduardo, sua resposta está boa, mas se puder, poste pelo menos o código js aqui, pois se os links se quebrarem, sua resposta fica inválida.

Comment: Obrigado, @Randrade! Boas práticas são boas práticas!!!

Comment: Editei apenas para adequação do snnipets, nenhum erro específico. Mas faltou você falar que está enviando com espaço. :)

Comment: Valeu mesmo! Bem, eu adicionei no comentário do código. Acho que estamos documentando bem a pergunta hehee

Comment: Agora sim, +1. Mas que pena que já existe uma resposta assim, e essa será fechada. Mas isso não inválida sua resposta.

Comment: O importante é que a gente documente bem as perguntas e as respostas no SOF em Português, assim, nossa comunidade cresce e vira referência.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, com `javascript` você pode utilizar o evento [onkeypress()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp) para realizar se o botão apertado foi o enter, se for você chama o `submit`, ficaria desta forma:

```html
  <input type="text" id="txtSearch" onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event);" />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" Value="Search" onclick="doSomething();" />

<script>
function searchKeyPress(e)
{
    // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function doSomething(){
  alert('submited');
}
</script>
```

Exemplo no [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/vkn5y2qq/)

Agora, caso queira utilizar jQuery, basta utilizar o evento [keyup()](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) para fazer a mesma verificação, desta forma:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtSearch"  />
    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" Value="Search"/>


<script>
$("#txtSearch").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#btnSearch").click();
    }
});
  
$('#btnSearch').click(function(){
  alert('test');
});
</script>
```

Exemlo no [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/vkn5y2qq/1/)

Fonte: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/155188/4843158)